# How to set language based on target?

Tags: ios, localization

I made an app (English) and I want the app for 2 more language (Dutch, French). How do I do that?
I tried with Localizable, but it works only if I changed the simulator/device language. Even if I change the language, I want that the language be the same, the target language.

Comment: what do you want actually, could you elabrate

Comment: Is this for testing/development purposes or you actually want to create separate apps to upload to the AppStore? If its for the first, you can just create some schemes that make use of launch arguments to set the language of the device. See here for more info about this: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/using-launch-arguments-to-test-localizations/

Comment: Hodson, I actually want to create separate apps to upload to the AppStore.

Comment: @cyph3r In English the first person pronoun is **always** capitalized. Stop suggesting such horrible edits, this is vandalism.